# Is it possible to transform a series of vectors from $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ while preserving the relative order of dot products?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, transformation

Given in input a series of vectors in the Integer coordinate space e.g.:

$ v1=\langle -1, -1\rangle, v2=\langle 2  -9 \rangle, v3=\langle -1 , 32 \rangle, v4=\langle 1, 5 \rangle$

is it possible to transform them in the domain of positive integers numbers, in such a way that the dot product relative order is preserved?

i.e.

v1 $\bullet$ v2 < v3 $\bullet$ v4

v1 $\bullet$ v2 > v1 $\bullet$ v4

etc...

Thanks!

**Edited**

- Removed the constraint on Real Number because it was irrelevant for the concrete problem.
- Modified the question asking for relative order rather than exact same dot product

Comment: Learn to use mathjax. For more info [click on this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Dot products of vectors with entries in $\mathbb{Z}^+$ will be positive integers themselves. For the list of vectors you provided, their dot products are not integers, so this isn't possible.

Comment: Thanks @EuYu I have removed the constraint on Real numbers because it is easy to workaround in the concrete problem.

Comment: @TonyRad But still, dot products between your given vectors are sometimes negative, whereas dot products between $\Bbb Z^+$ vectors are always positive

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen right, thanks. I have edited the question to remove the exact dot product and have rather a relative order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix a vector <$-1$,$1$>

Say $f$ be a function that maps from integer coordinate 2D space to the naturals that is order-preserving with respect to the dot product in the sense defined

<$-1$,$1$>.<$n$,$0$>=$-n$  (where . represents the usual dot product)

So clearly $f(<n,0>)$ is **strictly** less than $f(<n+1,0>)$ as <$-1$,$1$>.<$n$,$0$> is less than <$-1$,$1$>.<$n+1$,$0$> and f is order preserving in the sense defined in the question, and f(<$1$,$1$>) is a fixed positive number.

Also the range of $f$ is the natural numbers but we get an infinite decreasing sequence of natural numbers which is not possible, hence such an order preserving-map in the sense defined is not possible.